# Periodically save SQLite Memory-DB to file

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-backups

I have a program that runs continuously and saves data to a SQLite database every second.
I want to change this and use a memory database that saves to disk every 15 minutes instead.

My program is written in Java and I use the library [SQLite4Java](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/). It works well and I have a 'Job Queue' that handles the inserts with an ExecutorService in Java.

I have found out that the first time I write to file I can use 'SQLiteConnection.initializeBackup(File)' and after that DROP & CREATE the tables in memory and maybe use VACUUM, to clear memory. This works well, but later it gets tricky... How do I append/merge the new data from the memory-DB after another 15 minutes to the existing file?

Is there a standard approach to do this? Would it be good practice to simply fetch all data from each table in memory db (and lock it, to prevent further inserts), loop it through in and insert it in the file db?

Comment: Why the change to the memory DB?

Comment: Because I want to be able to take out the database-file from time to time and analyze it, that is hard when the program is continuously writing to it. Also I want to ease stress from the hard-drive (SSD).

Comment: Try using [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) instead.

Comment: That was interesting reading, I didn't know about WAL, but with that I will only reduce IO-operations with 50% and they will be almost equally frequent. It allows concurrent reading, but I do the analysis on a different (more powerful) machine.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html

Comment: https://litestream.io/ is another option for streaming modifications from one sqlite instance to a backup replica.